# Accessing a Kotlin Class With Javassist

Tags: java, kotlin, javassist

There is at the very least an illusion one can use the bytecode manipulator [javassist](https://www.javassist.org/) with `Kotlin` since there is an [isKotlin()](http://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/CtClass.html#isKotlin()) method. However, I cannot (but would like to) access a Kotlin class using this library.

Here is my directory structure:

```
kotlin_test
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   ├── assist.java
│   │   ├── kotlin
│   │   │   └── kotlintest.kt
```

I can find the "assist.java" class by saying `CtClass cc = cp.get('assist')`, but I cannot find the Kotlin class by using the statement `CtClass cc = cp.get('kotlintest')`. I believe it is not picking up the classpath because it is a kotlin file.

Does anyone know how I can access the class file?

**EDIT**
As requested, below is my `kotlintest.kt` class:

```
class kotlintest {
    // Hello World Program

    fun main(args : Array<String>) {
        println("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `kotlintest.kt` file look like?

Comment: Oh good idea. I have added `.kt` class file.

Comment: @DanielConnelly and Dcon2050 Why are you using two different accounts?

Comment: @Clijsters Oops. I am transitioning to `Dcon2050` as my old stack account is using a school email address that will expire soon. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Why not just update the e-mail address in your profile?

Comment: I would be surprised if this was a Javassist problem. I can access Kotlin classes from Javassist without any issues. Is the Kotlin class on your class path, i.e. can you access it normally from Java, e.g. in the line right before your `cp.get('kotlintest')` call, and do something like `kotlintest.main("foo")`? Maybe you rather have a build/run configuration problem with Maven, Gradle or your IDE.

Comment: @kriegaex Sorry, my bad. The form was hard to find... I found it and will be using this account from now on.

I get the following error message `Non-static "main(java.lang.String[]" cannot be referenced from a static context` when I try to attempt `kotlintest.main("foo")`.

Comment: Well, because I don't speak Kotlin and didn't know that what looked like a static main method at first glance is non-static despite the name. But I thought you know that speak Kotlin, thus can figure it out by yourself. Looks like I was wrong. Are you new to both Kotlin and Javassist, maybe to programming in general? Why are you combining two new things you have no experience with? Wouldn't one after another be better? Anyway, probably it would rather be something like `new kotlintest().main(null)` when called from Java. BTW, it is bad practice to name classes with all lower case characters.

Comment: If you "don't speak Kotlin", why are you answering my question? People that ask questions are the ones who lack information and those who answer them usually have information to share. If you don't know the answer, don't give one. You are criticizing the wrong person. Anyways, you are wrong about Kotlin. There is no `static` keyword; all classes are interpreted as static by the JVM from what I read. Furthermore, there is no `new` keyword. Please delete your comments if all you are giving are guesses -- they don't add anything to the answer. PS: I know Javassist and Kotlin (one after the other)

Comment: To clarify, the `new kotlintest().main(null)` line does work, but knowing Kotlin (where there is no `new`) didn't help me infer to that point. Still, my original question about Javassist remains unanswered as the class is not identified by javassist.